# Gradle exec commandLine not working for me

Tags: gradle, exec

I am trying to run an executable with arguments from gradle:

```
task deploy(dependsOn: jar) {
    exec {
        commandLine "javafxpackager -deploy -native -outdir ${deployDirName} -outfile ${jarBaseName} -srcfiles ./${project.buildDir}/${project.libsDirName}/${jarBaseName}-${project.version}.jar -appclass ${mainClass} -name ${jarBaseName} -title '${project.description}'"
    }
}
```

Gradle complains that the process ended up with non-zero return code, but if I copy the command and run it within bash terminal, it works flawlessly.

So what am I doing wrong?

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with this code: First, the `exec` call happens outside a task action (`doLast { ... }`). As a result, `exec` will get called for every single build invocation (even when typing `gradle help`), in the *configuration phase* of the build. Second, `commandLine` accepts a *list* of command line arguments, not a single string.

It's almost always better to use a task type than the corresponding method, so this becomes:

```
task deploy(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn jar
    commandLine "javafxpackager", "-deploy",  "-native", ...
}
```

To find out how to configure a particular task (type), check the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: great, thank you, it works now, and I was curious why deploy is called everytime. Cheers!

Comment: I also thought it accepts a string.  The documentation is bit unclear on this;  you need to look at the type of commandLine (List<String>) to figure it out.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec:commandLine